# Control of headers in a $http request

Tags: angularjs, ajax, caching

I am struggle with header caching in a request.

my resource is looks like:

```
method: 'GET',
cache: false,
headers: {
  session: auth.mySession()
}
```

Provider is also configured.

```
config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
 if (!$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = {};
 }
 $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache';
 $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Pragma'] = 'no-cache';
 }]).
```

In practice it doesn't work. 
Request is sent with a session while it is removed and
without the session while it's set.
I had to press Ctrl+F5.

Answer (score 1):

At last I realized that it is not about caching results, but caching headers themselves.

Headers are calculated just once at page initialization stage.
Right after that fact I came with an interceptor solution, which always injects valid session into a request's header.

```
config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('injectingSessionInterceptor');
}]).
service('injectingSessionInterceptor', ['auth', function (auth) {
    var ser = this;
    ser.request = function (config) {
        var session = auth.mySession();
        config.headers.session = session;
        return config;
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I was able to finally circumvent a caching issue - using this service to dynamically add Pragma and Cache-Control headers to my requests by looking for 'cache:true' in the config. Oddly angular was not refreshing the cache on its own.